# Add stylesheets and .js files to tinyMCE editor in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I would like to had some jquery files and stylesheets to the head of the tinyMCE editor of wordpress. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use an own plugin or the tinymce setup paramter

```
// Adds an observer to the onSaveContent event using tinyMCE.init
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed){
         ed.dom.loadCSS( 'url_to_your_css_file' );
      });
   }
});
```